# Tags not being removed from search suggestions

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

When you search for something that doesn't return any results, the Suggestions on the No Results page are not working as they should.

For example, the following search returns no results:

> [csv **[saveas]** **[powerbuilder]**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=csv+%5Bsaveas%5D+%5Bpowerbuilder%5D)

The suggestions I get for my search are:

> Suggestions:
>
> - Place your search terms in quotes to search for a phrase:
>
>   "csv saveas powerbuilder"
> - Use fewer words:
>   [csv [saveas] [<strike>powerbuilder</strike>]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=csv%20%5bsaveas%5d%20%5bpowerbuilder%5d)
>   [<strike>csv</strike> [saveas] [powerbuilder]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=csv+%5Bsaveas%5D+%5Bpowerbuilder%5D)
>   [csv [saveas] [<strike>powerbuilder</strike>]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=csv%20%5bsaveas%5d%20%5bpowerbuilder%5d)

Two issue here:

Firstly, I think the suggestions should remove the first word, remove the second word, ... remove the nth word and so on. In this instance, the second last and last suggestions are the same.

Secondly, the URLs for the suggestions don't remove the stuck-out word if it's a tag. The last suggestion's URL should be

> [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=csv+[saveas]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=csv+%5Bsaveas%5D)

since the **[powerbuilder]** tag is removed in the displayed font.

Comment: Refresh the search suggestions page, see what you get.

Comment: I get 3 results, with 1 duplicate, in a random order. In any case where the tag is displayed as being removed, the URL still includes the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is by design for the moment; it picks strikeouts at random.

As for the second part, this is now fixed, but.. well, did you ever feel like you just walked through a sewer?

`(?<=([\b ]|^))\[saveas](?=([\b ]|$))`

The problem had to do with the definition of "word boundary" `\b` when applied to strings like `[saveas]`