# StackOverflow Search "use fewer words" shows wrong link display

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

Search for "product stream" in StackOverflow, quotes included.  The "use fewer words" suggestions shows

- "product stream"
- "product stream"
- "product stream"

Even though the links do link to "product", "stream", "product".

Quite confusing.

Thanks.

Comment: What is "use fewer words" suggestions? Never heard of that... quite confusing ;-)

Comment: +1 - Replicated (though that exact search on Meta now links to this page, I got the result by searching for `"product <something else>"`. I would tell you what, but then presumably that wouldn't work any more! (Hint: replace `<something else> with `foo`)).

Comment: Oooh, now I understand. I missed the "quotes included" part. Replicated as well. Here's a "reproducable" link: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22product+stream%22

Comment: I've tried that a few times now, and  it changes what the links point to, i.e. first time: stream,product,stream; second time: product,product,stream.

Comment: I wanted to close this as dupe, but the dupe is set to `status-completed`. So you get a +1 (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27260/tags-not-being-removed-from-search-suggestions)

Answer (score 2):

All of these errors will be fixed in a build tonight - including those in @[Geoffrey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/151132/geoffrey-zheng)'s answer.  In the case of quoted phrases we won't suggest striking words out (since you're searching for a *very* exact match).

In cases where a quoted phrase is part of a larger query however, we will suggest striking out the entire phrase...if that would get you any results.

Answer (score 0):

Search for `"stack exchange" inbox`:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22stack+exchange%22+inbox

Comment: Cosmic ray... it works now. I swear to King Atwood, Joel the Apostle, and St. Skeet that I didn't fake the screenshot.